# ES6 build chain python backend (flask) not SPA

Tags: python, flask, build, ecmascript-6, vuejs2

I am just trying to understand the best way to setup by dev environment. My stack is Vue.js (maybe react if i can get the build i want in place) and flask back-end. This is **not** a single page application and flask is serving the html pages with jinja2 templates. Some pages will have no vue.js others will have MANY components.

What i want is to be able to code in ES6 (currently using vue.js in normal es5 javascript with no transpiling). I want to be able to code in python on the flask stuff, i want the flask dev server running and picking up changes to files and restarting.

I am using pycharm as my editor and have only a little bit of knowledge on the javascript build process.

Edit i file in my editor, refresh by browser page and have all the server side changes and es6 changes complied and available on the page.

If this is in the wrong place please direct me to the right place before just closing.

Comment: Are you using webpack for building your javascript? Because then you can run the webpack dev server while also running your flask dev server. The flask dev server should pick up all jinja changes, while the webpack server should react to all changes you do in your vue files and hot reload the your frontend. If you want es6 support you might want to integrate babel for es6 into your webpack config.

Comment: When running in development mode on a js file save its not actually saved to disk but held in memory i would need to edit the javascript, build for production, and then could see the changes in the flask server.

Comment: Figured it what i needed was this plugin for web pack https://github.com/gajus/write-file-webpack-plugin i still have to run both servers but can completely ignore the one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to run this plug in in webpack
https://github.com/gajus/write-file-webpack-plugin. Now i still have to run the dev server but it also writes to disk to my static js files for flask and flask picks up the changes.

I still have both servers running but only need to watch and pay attention to the python one.